# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp64\www\bluepeatshop\db_connect.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

db_connect.php

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;

    public function connect()
    {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $this->conn = new mysqli_connect(host:DB_HOST,username:DB_USER,passwd:DB_PASSWORD,dbname:DB_DATABASE);
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
define(DB_HOST, "localhost");
define(DB_USER, "root");
define(DB_PASSWORD, "");
define(DB_DATABASE, "bluepeatshop");
?>
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp64\www\bluepeatshop\db_connect.php
        on line 9
```

Comment: Hi there. As a general thumbs, I would recommend you to get a simple code working and then (affer your simple code is working) make a class of it. Otherwise I think you are creating yourself more trouble than solution.

Comment: why do you refer it as host:DB_HOST,username:DB_USER and so on. As those constants are already defined you can directly use DB_HOST,DB_USER like that

Answer (score 0):

Your constant usage is incorrect, try changing your db connect string as below,

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;

    public function connect()
    {
    require_once 'config.php';
    $this->conn = new mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```